# Black sticky goo coming from furnace

Tags: furnace

Can anyone tell me what this is coming out of the furnace....

[image]

[image]

Comment: we can tell you what it looks like, not what it is ... looks like tar

Comment: Looks like creosote.  Do not use furnace before you have it cleaned.  Can and probably will cause a fire.  Make sure you clean the furnace and all pipes and chimney.  Also have furnace checked for proper operation.

Comment: Gas , oil , coal , or other , furnace fuel ?

Comment: I've seen this in horror movies.  Get out while you still can.

Comment: Unburned fuel residue; without knowing your fuel, no more specific than that. In any case, when was it last serviced and combustion checked? That's a sign that the combustion is probably not clean, and fuel (money) is being wasted.

Comment: Can you step back further from the furnace and take a picture so that we have a better idea of where the stuff is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the remains of cork insulating tape.  It was likely applied during installation or repair - rather than 'coming out' of the furnace.  I would want to check to make sure the operating plenum temperature is not excessive.  Cork insulating tape is better suited to cold rather than to hot areas of the HVAC system.